# CSS - font is being hidden in button while resizing browser window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, resize

**CSS**

```
   #category{
    width: 85%;
    height: 65%;
    //border: thin darkgray solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    bottom: 0;
}
    .interest_categories{

        width: 21%;
        height: 15%;
        border: thin darkgrey solid;
        margin-left:10px ;
        margin-top: 10px;
        float: left;
    }

    .interest_categories input{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-size: 1em;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="category" style="width: 96%; margin-top: 5px; height: 75%; top: 0; border: thin red solid;">
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="films" value="Films"  style="background: #ffc561; color: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="music" value="Music"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="dance" value="Dance"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="reading" value="Reading"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="design_art" value="Design & Art"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="photography" value="Photography"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="science" value="Science"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="it" value="IT"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="technology" value="Technology"  style="background: #ffc561; color: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="business" value="Business"  style="background: #ffc561; color: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="entrepreneurship" value="Entrepreneurship"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="sports" value="Sports"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="games" value="Games"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="psychology" value="Psychology"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button"  id="humor" value="Humor"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="travel" value="Travel"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>

            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="nature" value="Nature"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>

            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="food_drink" value="Food & Drink"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>

            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="fashion" value="Fashion"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>

            <div class="interest_categories">
                <input type="button" id="history" value="History"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>

        </div><!--Category-->
```

Here it is,
I want my font , not to be hidden even when i resize my window.
when I resize browser window , the fonts are being hidden as shown in image . so i want to do that when I resize my window, then the `categories` should fit properly.

[image: fonts are being hidden in image]

Comment: You can't do that..text is not adjustable to **element size**. You would need javascript.

Comment: can i use font-size-adjust? but it is only for firefox. or is there any way that i can put down the extra text in button.?

Comment: will you please give me your full code?

Comment: @Black Bird... given

Comment: That's not what `font-size-adjust` does.

Comment: okay.. then is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Nope...your buttons are fixed size and so is the text...you can't get the same amount of text in a smaller box...it just won't fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use `Bootstrap` actually. You have to divide your every `row` in four divisions.

```
3 + 3 + 3 + 3
3 + 3 + 3 + 3
3 + 3 + 3 + 3
3 + 3 + 3 + 3
3 + 3 + 3 + 3
```

You have not fixed anything in Bootstrap. I have edited your code by Bootstrap. May be it's not 100% of your answer, But I think you will be able to redesign it with your own knowledge.

```
<div class="container" id="category" style="top: 0; border: thin red solid;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="films" value="Films"  style="background: #ffc561; color: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="music" value="Music"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="dance" value="Dance"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="reading" value="Reading"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
    </div>


   <div class="row">
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="films" value="Films"  style="background: #ffc561; color: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="music" value="Music"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="dance" value="Dance"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="reading" value="Reading"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="films" value="Films"  style="background: #ffc561; color: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="music" value="Music"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="dance" value="Dance"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="reading" value="Reading"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="films" value="Films"  style="background: #ffc561; color: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="music" value="Music"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="dance" value="Dance"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="reading" value="Reading"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="films" value="Films"  style="background: #ffc561; color: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="music" value="Music"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="dance" value="Dance"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
            <div class="interest_categories col-md-3">
                <input type="button" id="reading" value="Reading"  style="color: #a1a1a1; background: white;">
            </div>
</div>

     </div>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #category{
    //border: thin darkgray solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    bottom: 0;
}
    .interest_categories{

        border: thin darkgrey solid;
        float: left;
    }

    .interest_categories input
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
```